# Try to show image but shows a broken link instead

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, image

I want to show a picture in my code but for some reason I get a big white almost blank page with a broken link img. I want to show the image and along with any other information.
I also want to resize the image(so it doesnt cover the whole page). 
The code:

```
<?php

session_start()

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<div id="Container">

<div id="header">
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
</div>

<div id="navigation">

<?php

include_once "navigation.php";

?>

</div>

<div id="Content">

<?php

if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
$Name = $_GET['search'];
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Could not connect to the server!");
mysql_select_db("pictures") or die ("That database could not be found!");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM picture WHERE Name='$Name'") or die ("The query could not be completed, please try again later!");
    if (mysql_num_rows($wepquery) !=1) {
        die ("That name could not be found!");
    }
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC, 0)) {
        $dbName = $row['Name'];
        $dbCreator = $row['Creator'];
        $dbDescription = $row['Description'];
        $imageData = $row['Image'];
    }
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    if($Name != $dbName) {
        die ("There has been a fatal error. Please try again.");
    }
?>
<h2><?php echo $Name; ?></h2>
<br />
<table>
    <tr><td>Creator: <?php echo $dbCreator;?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Description:<br /><?php echo $dbDescription;?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Picture:<br /><?php echo $imageData;?></td></tr>
</table>

<?php
} else die ("You need to specify a submission!");

?>

</div>

</div>

</html>
```

The database:

id, Name, Creator, Description, Image_name, Image(mediumblob).

The last two fields as you can see is dedicated to pictures. Yes I know about PDO and MySQLi, but I just want to finish this code first. Any help?

Comment: Have you checked the image path and verified that the image exists?

Comment: have you verified if the constructed image link is correct ?

Comment: The image does exist. Its a .png file with a name and all.
Image_name: Shotgun.png,
Image: [BLOB - 46.1 kB]

Comment: I hope you are aware of the vulnerability of SQL injection in your code and the use of deprecated `mysql_*` functions. It's fine to play with them, but please never do these in production code.

Comment: @AlvinWong
I am aware of that and I am playing around with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images need to either be served by URL or the blob needs to be converted to a data URI like so:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Creator: <?php echo $dbCreator;?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Description:<br /><?php echo $dbDescription;?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Picture:<br /><?php echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode( $imageData ) . "' />"; ?></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want image you need to enclose it with image tags. assume if your $imageData contains the location of the image then you can do the following.

```
<img src='<?php echo $imageData;?>' ... />
```

if your `$imageData` contains actual binary data of an image you need to create a separate call to a php script to return the imageData. and make the call to be the src attribute of an img tag.

Answer (score 0):

is your path exactly pointing toward the image? have checked "../../" ? another question, is your image really inside an image tag? there must be something like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $imagePath; ? />
```